# How to get data from web service in ADF mobile

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm new to ADF mobile application development. I'm currently blocked in a scenario. I have a web service(from third party) which needs  to retrieve data. In soapUI, the web service will retrieve the response only when there is this security tag. Otherwise it will give response as invalid security. The web service looks like this:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/" xmlns:get="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/get_login/">
           <soapenv:Header>
              <xx:SOAHeader>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xx:Responsibility>XXX</xx:Responsibility>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xx:RespApplication>XXX</xx:RespApplication>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xx:SecurityGroup>XXX</xx:SecurityGroup>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xx:NLSLanguage>XXX</xx:NLSLanguage>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xx:Org_Id>XXX</xx:Org_Id>
              </xx:SOAHeader>

<The portion which is excluded from the soap, but which is required for getting response>

<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                    <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXX</wsse:Password>
                    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">XXX</wsse:Nonce>
                    <wsu:Created>2013-02-13T08:58:50.649Z</wsu:Created>
                 </wsse:UsernameToken>
              </wsse:Security>
<The portion which is excluded from the soap, but which is required for getting response>

           </soapenv:Header>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <get:InputParameters>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <get:P_USERNAME>XXX</get:P_USERNAME>
              </get:InputParameters>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried the steps described in ADF mobile tutorial to get web service data. But I'm getting response code 500 from the server. I tried the steps for secured web service also. But I'm not sure which security policy has been implemented in the web service. I tried with oracle/wss_username_client_token_policy and some others but didn't succeed. Later I tried by creating web service client/proxy. But as Oracle ADF only supports java 1.4, I got errors in the generated code(errors on generics and annotation).

The WSDL for the web service is as follows:

```
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/get_login/" name="XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/get_login/">
<include schemaLocation="http://27.251.157.211:8000/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/APPS_XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_GET_LOGIN.xsd"/>
</schema>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/csf/soaprovider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/">
<element name="SOAHeader">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="Responsibility" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
<element name="RespApplication" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
<element name="SecurityGroup" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
<element name="NLSLanguage" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
<element name="Org_Id" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
</schema>
</types>
<message name="GET_LOGIN_Input_Msg">
<part name="header" element="tns:SOAHeader"/>
<part name="body" element="tns1:InputParameters"/>
</message>
<message name="GET_LOGIN_Output_Msg">
<part name="body" element="tns1:OutputParameters"/>
</message>
<portType name="XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_PortType">
<operation name="GET_LOGIN">
<input message="tns:GET_LOGIN_Input_Msg"/>
<output message="tns:GET_LOGIN_Output_Msg"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_Binding" type="tns:XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_PortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="GET_LOGIN">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://XXX:8000/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/"/>
<input>
<soap:header message="tns:GET_LOGIN_Input_Msg" part="header" use="literal"/>
<soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_Service">
<port name="XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_Port" binding="tns:XX_FS_MOB_LOGIN_Binding">
<soap:address location="http://XXX:8000/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xx_fs_mob_login/"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Please help me to figure out a solution for this.

Thanks in advance
Rino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get far in accessing a secure Web service directly from ADF Mobile if you don't know the type of security it uses.

If you can create a proxy client that invokes the web service, then one solution is to run that on the server, and expose that client as a web service that the ADF Mobile layer can access.

Comment: Thanks Shay....I searched a lot on this issue, and managed to get it done with this solution...